# Python 'print' statement and arguments

Tags: python

I'm an experienced C++ developer, but am just getting my feet wet with Python for a project at work.  I'm having some basic problems and Google has been less than helpful.  I suspect something about my environment is funny, but I have no clue how to diagnose it.  I wrote a simple script that merely prints an argument to the screen, but I am getting an error when running it (python args.py):

```
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
File "args.py", line 4
print arg0
```

For reference, there is a carrot underneath the 0 of arg0.  The script in question:

```
import sys

firstArg = sys.argv[0]
print firstArg
```

I'm sure this is something really dumb, but Python is such a foreign thing, coming from C++.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  If it is Python 3.x, then you need to call `print` as a function: `print(firstArg)`.

Comment: It's most likely 3 and you need `print(firstArg)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems pretty obvious. The traceback says you have a SyntaxError on line 4, therefore `print firstArg` isn't valid Python.

The *not* obvious part is that a *lot* of examples on the Internet use syntax like that. This is because in Python 2.X versions, `print` was a statement. [Since Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), print is a function. Try `print(firstArg)` instead.

*Protip: If you want to enable the* `print` *function in Python 2, use* `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  None of the tutorials I was reading mentioned the syntax difference between Python 2.x and 3.x.  I am using Python 3.2.3 at the moment.

Comment: Sadly, most of the Python community is still stuck on Python 2.X, due to dependencies not yet being ported. If at all possible, I recommend sticking with Python 3!

Answer (score 1):

I can understand that the print function of Python may be different for C or C++ developers because of its features.
The syntax that you use is for python 2 (now in End Of Life status). There are many differences between Python 2 and python 3.
In this case, the print was a statement in Python 2 but function in Python3.
Here is the correct syntax for print function in Python3.

```
print(firstArg)
```

Brackets are important because print is a function. The print function in Python has some [parameters](https://holycoders.com/python-print-function/) which make it even more powerful.